Spotfire ironpython: how to set multiple expressions on a box plot x axis?
I'm trying to automate creating a box plot in Spotfire with the API. I can set the axis column by myVis.XAxis.Expression = '', but I couldn't find anything in the API reference to add multiple columns like you can if you build the plot manually. Is this possible to do?

can you elaborate and show an example of what you are trying to achieve?
